# How do i create a notification in outlook using VSTO

Tags: outlook, notifications, vsto

Is is possible to create a notification in outlook similar to the "Updates available" notification with VSTO?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom horizontal Task Pane that can approximate that UI. The alternative is building your own completely custom UI but it is very difficult: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/.

As for auto-updating, you can deploy your add-in using ClickOnce and new versions will be detected and installed automatically: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx

Or you can build your own similar deployment mechanism with a manifest and source installation files on your own website.

Answer (score 0):

No, that functionality is not exposed or documented.

Comment: Thanks, its what I suspected but I thought it was worth an ask

Comment: Do you know of any other methods for creating a notification for the user, I can't seem to find anything in the VSTO docs

Comment: VSTO does not do anything other than Outlook Object Model does.